# What probability distribution does this data fit?

Tags: probability-distributions, brownian-motion

I have been studying brownian motion for my undergraduate capstone project, and I have been looking at the range of the values that brownian motion takes on. To get a computational idea of what is going on, I wrote a matlab script that would run 100,000 simulations of brownian motion on t=[0,1] and save the range of each run. I then made a histogram of the ranges, and I have been looking to see if they follow some known PDF. I was wondering if anyone here could help me figure out what this distribution might be. I have scaled the Y axis to make it a PDF instead of leaving it as a count like it would be in a histogram.

[image: Link to Histogram]

Comment: looks like log-normal...

Comment: Thanks, I just looked up log-normal, and it does look similar. That isn't a distribution that I am very familiar with. I will have to see if it fits the data well enough to point me in that direction. Also, if anybody has any other distributions it might be, I'm open to those too.

Comment: @JosephBergthold Having whipped up a quick simulation of what I think you're doing (matlab/octave: a = cumsum(randn(nsteps, npaths))/sqrt(nsteps); range = max(a)-min(a); )  (For reference I get a mean of 1.58). I get skewness(log(range))  to be robustly positive (though small), so I don't think it is exactly lognormal.

Comment: @JosephBergthold Actually, looking at the fit and realizing that mean I computed is suspiciously close to sqrt(e), I'm going to take back some of my confidence that it's not lognormal. This is brownian motion, so it is probably analytically tractable, but I don't have the wherewithal right now.